# Disconnect viewport background from environment lighting?

Tags: 3d-view, lighting, world

I need the viewport background to be gray, and I need the Scene Lighting and Scene World to be active in the viewport, but I do NOT want the background to emit ambient light. I can make this happen with a Light Path node, but I was hoping for an easier way.

The viewport background should just be a 2D user interface setting. It should not be an always-on source of environment light. I need to be able to see and select black wireframe objects, so I can't just set the world background color to black. I need a gray background that does not emit light. So if I create an object and do not add any lights, the viewport should be gray and the object should be absolutely black.

I can disable the setting "Viewport Header Menu > Viewport Shading > Scene World" and set the Strength to zero, but this will also disable the environment lighting, any Irradiance Maps, and probably a bunch of other stuff that I need.

The setting "World Properties > Viewport Display > Color" only functions if the Render Engine is set to Workbench.

So how can I decouple the viewport background color from environment lighting? It appears that Eevee and Cycles do not have a concept of default directional lighting like Workbench does. The default lighting in Eevee and Cycles comes from the world background, and the viewport background also comes from the world background.

I just need the viewport background to be a background and not a light source. This is the only way I can fully control the lighting and also be able to see and select black wireframes. The Light Path method seems to work, but it's arcane and overly complicated.

Thanks

Comment: Hello :). You could simply make the background transparent. Rendertab > Film > Transparent.

Comment: That does not work at all, sorry. Viewport background is still identical to World background, and it's still emitting light into the scene.